# background image not loading in meteor

Tags: css, meteor, jsx

Hi so I'm trying to recreate the HBO login page (w/o working links) and everything seems to be loading except for the background image. I'm thinking the problem is sizing the image(?) but not exactly sure because the background seems to just be white instead of the image.

i have all images in the public/images folder and call the background image in my css code with

```
  background: url('./public/images/tile.jpeg');
}
```

but this is what's currently showing up. [sample hbo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmnA0.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `public` in the path. Try:
  `background: url('/images/tile.jpeg');`